# Did not attempt to load JSON data because the request Content-Type was not &#39;application/json&#39;

Tags: flask, axios, flask-restful

I'm following a flask tutorial on https://towardsdatascience.com/simple-way-to-deploy-machine-learning-models-to-cloud-fd58b771fdcf where we try to deploy a logistic regression model on cloud using flask. I'm stuck on the flask part.

the cloud_test.py code:

```
# Serve model as a flask application

import pickle
import numpy as np
from flask import Flask, request

model = None
app = Flask(__name__)


def load_model():
    global model
    # model variable refers to the global variable
    with open('iris_trained_model.pkl', 'rb') as f:
        model = pickle.load(f)


@app.route('/')
def home_endpoint():
    return 'Hello World!'


@app.route('/predict', methods=['POST'])
def get_prediction():
    # Works only for a single sample
    if request.method == 'POST':
        data = request.get_json()  # Get data posted as a json
        data = np.array(data)[np.newaxis, :]  # converts shape from (4,) to (1, 4)
        prediction = model.predict(data)  # runs globally loaded model on the data
    return str(prediction[0])


if __name__ == '__main__':
    load_model()  # load model at the beginning once only
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=5000, debug=True)
```

When I run this file and pass " curl -X POST 127.0.0.1:5000/predict -H 'Content-Type:application/json' -d '[5.9,3.0,5.1,1.8]' " as a command, I get the following error:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang=en>
<title>400 Bad Request</title>
<h1>Bad Request</h1>
<p>Did not attempt to load JSON data because the request Content-Type was not &#39;application/json&#39;.</p>
```

I have referred to other soultions here on this issue and I'm unable to find any solution that resolves my issue too.